# the attribute send by jsp is nowhere in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the parameter `monitorScreen` in my servlet from following url.

```
GET /Random/servlet/ps.commands.GetCmd?monitorScreen=true HTTP/1.1
```

but when i look for variable or value monitorScreen in this particular servlet i am not able to find it anywhere in the servlet

Comment: Cannot understand your question clearly

Comment: that doesnt mean you need to down vote it

Comment: atleast I let you know the reason for downvoting, I can't cancel the downvote unless it is edited. Most of the people wouldn't have bothered to comment why they downvoted.

Comment: i dont want you to cancel the downvote. i just simply want to know that if my jsp page is calling some servlet and sending an attribute (monitorScreen=true)to it and i don't find that attribute in that servlet

Comment: Post also snippet of JSP, servlet and web.xml

Comment: I cancelled the downvote..

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you would retrieve parameters in servlet from following URL,

```
www.someServer.com/somePage.jsp?monitorScreen=true
```

Then in `doGet` method of servlet,

```
String value = request.getParameter("monitorScreen");
```